# python :: iterate through nested JSON results

Tags: python, json, loops, iteration

iterating through `JSON` `results` can get quite confusing at times. 
say I have a `function`like so:

```
def get_playlist_owner_ids(query):

    results = sp.search(q=query, type='playlist')
    id_ = results['playlists']['items'][0]['owner']['id']
    return (id_)
```

I can fetch the `id_`, it works.

but how do I iterate using a `for i in x` loop so I `return` ALL `ids_`?

Comment: All of which `id`s? You need to show us the structure of your `results` data structure (and which level or levels you want the `id` values from) in order for this to be answerable. Maybe you want `[x['owner']['id'] for x in results['playlists']['items']]`, but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
results['playlists']['items'][0]['owner']['id']
                              ^___ this is a list index
```

Thus:

```
for item in results['playlists']['items']:
    print(item['owner']['id'])
```

It is often convenient to make intermediate variables in order to keep things more readable.

```
playlist_items = results['playlists']['items']
for item in playlist_items:
    owner = item['owner']
    print(owner['id'])
```

This is assuming I have correctly guessed the structure of your object based on only what you have shown. Hopefully, though, these examples give you some better ways of thinking about splitting up complex structures into meaningful chunks.

Comment: you have guessed correctly. although a list comprehension would return the data structure like this: `[u'handiofiblood', u'holgar_the_red', u'thedoomlord', u'slokra', u'1121479704', u'joakim56789', u'twiggywasp', u'killnot', u'slashxero', u'sandpapersparkle']`, therefore in a more efficient way for further processing, it wouldn't be as much readable. I could also append the results to an empty list. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? You can use generator to achieve your goal

```
def get_playlist_owner_ids(query):
    results = sp.search(q=query, type='playlist')
    for item in results['playlists']['items']:
        yield item['owner']['id']
```

Comment: Why a generator? The whole structure already appears to be loaded into memory.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over `results['playlists']['items']`, or, better yet, use list comprehension:

```
def get_playlist_owner_ids(query):

    results = sp.search(q=query, type='playlist')
    return [x['owner']['id'] for x in results['playlists']['items']]
```

Answer (score 0):

In practice your document is something like this:

```
{ "playlists": {
    "items":[
        {"owner":{"id":"1"},...},                 
        {"owner":{"id":"2"},...},
        {"owner":{"id":"3"},...},
        ...,
}
```

So you have to loop over the list of items.

You can do something like this

```
ids = []
items = results['playlists']['items']
for item in items:
    ids.append(item['owner']['id'])

return ids
```

Or if you want to a one line:

```
ids = [item['owner']['id'] for owner in results['playlists']['items']]
```

Comment: Your one-liner is not quite right. `owner['owner']['id']`